# Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again

Tags: flask

When I run this, 404 error is been shown. Please help me solving this:

```
from flask import Flask
   app = Flask(__name__)
   @app.route("/") 
   def index():
         return "<h1> Hello Puppy! </h1>"
   @app.route("/information")
   def info():
       return "<h1> Puppies are Cute </h1>"
   @app.route("/Puppy/<name>")
   def puppy(name):
        return "<h1> This is a page for {} </h1>".format(name)
   if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run()
```

Comment: provide steps how you run this and for what point it showing error

Comment: If i run this only the first route is getting executed and the remaining routes are not getting executed.The error shows "Not Found. The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again".